# Raspberry Pi vs BeagleBone torrentbox

Tags: raspbian, networking, web

I'm planning to make an always on torrentbox, I get my internet from a 4g usb dongle modem, but I've very limited experience with such boards. From what I read on the internet, it seems BeagleBone is little bit more powerful and has an easier time setting up than Rpi, but it is slightly more expensive and I'm on a shoestring budget. Which board is better suited for my kind of project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main things that I would consider are:

1) Is cost an issue?  The Raspberry Pi is cheaper, but the beaglebone black comes with a power cord and onboard storage.  Unless you have an adequate power cord and sd card lying around, the Raspberry Pi will cost about the same.

2) As far as ease of setup goes... Both can run full versions of linux.  At the very least, you have a compete graphical interface for all setup purposes, so I'd say their setup effort is about equal.

3) Is speed an issue?  The raspberry pi's ethernet is slightly more powerful, and with overclocking (built in support) the raspberry pi's CPU is comparable to the beaglebone black's.

For just a torrent box, I honestly don't think either is really better, than the other.  They're so close, just pick whichever you like better.

Comment: Thanks! you're right, either of them will do for my project. But later on I want to further explore and experiment and I find that rpi has a lot of material, examples, tutorials online. So I'm more inclined to go for a rpi now.